# Canvas. Как задать путь персонажу?

Tags: javascript, canvas

Как можно перемещать персонажа по определённому пути?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Нужно чтобы "мадам" добралась до точки на карте, но останавливалась на каждой точке и при нажатии на кнопку "в универ" продолжала путь. т.е при нажатии кнопки делала ход.

```
 const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    const hero = new Image();
    hero.src = '../img/hero.png';
    let x = 430;
    let y = 425; 
    hero.onload = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(hero,x,y,31,86)
    }
    const go = document.querySelector('.go_university');
    let tur = 0;
    let timer;
    let direction = 0;
    go.addEventListener('click',()=>{
        tur += 1;
        turn();
    })

    function turn(){
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,960,630);
        direction+=1;

        if(direction<=15){
            x-=2;
            y=(y-2/3);
        }else if(direction >= 15 && direction <= 28){
            x-=2;
            y=(y-2);
        }else if(direction >=28 && direction <=48){
            x-=2;
            y=(y+3/6);
        }else if(direction >= 48 && direction <=70){
            x-=2;
            y=(y+3/6);
        }


        timer = setTimeout(turn,60);
        ctx.drawImage(hero,x,y,31,86)
    }
```

Вот такой код я написал, дальше не могу сообразить. Как восстанавливать анимацию, при клике. И вообще правильно ли я делаю расчёты. Или тупой просто.